# (not) displaying optional fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Disclaimer: I'm a bloody rookie)

My model contains some optional values. It seems that they may not exist at all (==nil) or that they may exist but are empty. In both cases, I don't want to show anything in my view. Currently, I do it like this:

```
<% if @score.lyricist and not @score.lyricist.empty? %>
<p>
  <strong>Lyricist:</strong>
  <%= @score.lyricist %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

This seems awkward and repetitive. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) method is the opposite of `blank?` method.

```
<% if @score.lyricist.present? %>
<p>
  <strong>Lyricist:</strong>
  <%= @score.lyricist %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`blank?` method will check both nil and empty values

```
<% unless @score.lyricist.blank? %>
<p>
  <strong>Lyricist:</strong>
  <%= @score.lyricist %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank?)